# Change the file descriptor offset

Tags: java, file

Now I'm making a little program in Java which must read a really big file. Due to this thing, I want to access to the file but not read completely each time, then my question is the following: can I change the offset of the file descriptor with a simple instruction or the only solution that I have is read all the previous lines which I don't need?

In other words, can I simulate the lseek command in my input file?

I think it's not necessary this time, but if someone wants code, I'll post it.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want [`RandomAccessFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Specifically, you want the [seek(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method.

Comment: Thank you! This is that i was looking for. I've been reading the `RandomAccessDile` API and now I have the trouble fixed. I only must save the offset with `getFilePointer()` and the following time that I read, I'll move the offset with the `seek(long)`function. ;-)